# Altium: Design rule for single object in PCB

Tags: altium

I have a *polygon pour* whose contact to a pad shouldn't have a thermal relief, so the plane can dissipate the component's heat. All other polygons should keep the default rule, with reliefs.

**How do I make a rule that targets that single polygon pour?**

The polygon is named "5V_Dissipator". I've tried creating a rule that targets this polygon with `InNamedPolygon('5V_Dissipator')`, but when I repour it the *PolygonConnect*, which is set to `All`, always dominates making the contact with the pad have a thermal relief.

[image]

I've also tried `Name = '5V_Dissipator'` and `InComponent('5V_Dissipator')`, that don't work. I don't understand how this is supposed to work.

If I remove the thermal relief from *PolygonConnect* (by changing this rule's properties) it works well, the polygon repours correctly.

Comment: You need to put your specialized rule before the general rule in the list of all Polygon Connect Style rules. Altium goes through the rules in order and applies the first rule it finds that fits. So if you have the 'All' rule first, that rule will always be used.

Comment: You need to use `Where the first object matches "InNamedPolygon('5V_Dissipator')"` and `Where the second object matches "IsVia"`. And you need to put that rule's priority ahead of the default, as ThePhoton mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

**I needed to set [rules priorities](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/PCB_Dlg-PriorityEditor_Form((Edit+Rule+Priorities))_AD).**

In the *PCB Rules and Constraints Editor*, I selected the bottom most group selecting the rules I want pro prioritize, named *Polygon Connect Style*, shown below.

[image]

Then I click *Priorities...* button on the bottom right, which brings up the *Edit Rule Priorities* dialog. Here you can change the priority of the rules.

## Query for single object

The query `Name = '5V_Dissipator'` was the only one that worked, from the three queries mentioned in the question. I believe you can use any query of the type `PropertyName = 'propertyValue'` to target any individual object.

## Wildcards in queries

Queries support [wildcards](https://www.altium.com/documentation/15.1/display/ADES/((Query+Operators))_AD#!QueryOperators-WildCardCharacters) if you use the *Like* operator. For example, `Name Like '*_Dissipator'` can be used to target all objects whose name ends in *_Dissipator*.

## Testing queries

By far the best method to test the query you're creating is the *PCB Filter* Panel, shown bellow. It will dynamically show you what you're targeting.

[image]

Comment: Good job that you added your own detailed findings.